# How do you make multiple 'menu' buttons in Swift that are on multiple ViewControllers navigate to the same VC?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm making my first app.. But I'm having a bit of trouble understanding some logic with switching View Controllers.

I currently have 6 View Controllers on my main storyboard. All of them have the same three menu buttons at the bottom - Home, Completed and Settings.

I understand you can CTRL+drag on each button, but it seems really inefficient. So I'd like to do it through code, and target each 'Home' button on every VC, every 'Completed' button on every VC etc so if you click on it on every page it takes you to the right VC.

Will I have to manually code each  of the 6 pages so it navigates across, or is there a way of targeting every 'Home' button so it works with just one line of code instead of dragging it on each VC?

Hopefully that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: If you see that as a disadvantage of using storyboards, then maybe you should have a look into how to create UIs from code. Personally, I liked storyboards for a long time. But I saw that it's worth the effort to build everything from code because it is way easier to reuse stuff. A lot of teams nowadays work without storyboards because it is easier to work with multiple people on projects without storyboards.

Comment: Storyboards work great in some respects, with my brief knowledge up to now.. But I think longer term coding them will be more efficient. Do you have a link to a site you’d recommend with good info into coding them instead?

Comment: Actually I was about to share a bookmark to a medium article but that was already deleted. This one looks good: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/8/2/building-a-uikit-user-interface-programmatically If you start building your UIs from code, you should also google for MVVM Architecture and maybe MVVM-C after that.

Comment: Thanks again for the response, I really appreciate it. I think I’ll try fully coding it from scratch - quick question though if that’s okay? Is the only way to visualise the app and how it’s looking by running the simulator? I’m assuming it doesn’t update on the storyboard as you’re doing it...

Comment: There is an interesting way of visualizing views and view controllers using a SwiftUI wrapper to show the view in XCode Previews. It is described here: https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/xcode-previews/  Personally I do not use this method. It is more hardware consuming then just running it in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should think about using a `UITabBarController` instead of `UIButton`s for that, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

Basically you have a `UITabBarController` with your three view controllers ("Home, Completed and Settings") then you get three buttons at the bottom. Whenever you press one of the buttons, the `UITabBarController` "knows" which view controller belongs to that and presents this view controller.

Comment: I think this is a lot better than my buttons. I’ll have a play with it and see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom button class like this:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToVC), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    @objc func goToVC() {
        print("going")
        // your logic
    }
}
```

And then in the storyboard, on the identity inspector, you set the class to your class i.e "MyButton"

Comment: Thanks! I think I’ll apply this to my other buttons around the app, but go with TabBarController and try that instead. Appreciate the response though.